# Как умножить первое на второе число с одной переменной?

Tags: алгоритм, javascript

Например `var str = 2975;` нужно умножить первое на второе `2*9`.

**Обновление**

У мене почему-то не суммируется если записать вот так.

```
 var morth = 10;  
 var date = 16;

 var morth1 = (morth).toString();
 var date1 = (date).toString();

 // Складываем цифры дня и месяца рождения

 var date_res = date1[0] + date1[1];
 var morth_res = morth1[0] + morth1[1];

 var resultat = date_res + morth_res;
 document.write(resultat);
```

Comment: @Surfer, потому что оператор `+` не только складывает числа, но и конкатенирует строки, что и выполняется в первую очередь для строк. Используйте `parseInt()` для преобразования строк в целые числа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```
var str = (2975).toString();
alert(str[0] * str[1]);
```

**Обновление**

[[@Surfer](/users/20329/surfer)](/users/20329/surfer), или parseInt, как предложил [[@Etki](/users/16095/etki)](/users/16095/etki), или так можно:

```
var date_res = +date1[0] + +date1[1];
var morth_res = +morth1[0] + +morth1[1];
```

P.S. Я бы может и так сделал:

```
var morth = 10,
    date = 16,
    digits = morth + '' + date,
    sum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++){
    sum += +digits[i];
}
console.log(sum); // 8
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: спасибо, но почему то возвращается "undefined" когда переменная "morth" равна 1 или 01

Comment: @Surfer, Потому, что индексов, которые вы указываете вручную - может и не быть. Обратите вниание на мой последкий код в постскриптуме.